# Are 110 MB/s write speeds for an nvme normal?

Tags: ssd, nvme

I am getting 110 MB/s crysitalDiskMark

[image]

write speeds on my Asus Strix g15 g513, which has a INTEL 670P SSD the model number is (SSDPEKNU512GZ) they have an advertised 3000 MB/s read speed and 1600 MB/s write speed. Also if I try copying a file from a portable ssd drive to the nvme the speed plummets to 20 MB/s (The file size is 12 GB). However, if I copy a file that is around 1 GB the speed is fine. Also if I set the cyrstialDiskMark setting to 1 Gib I get better results

[image: Result with 1 Gib].

Is this normal? Is the nvme faulty?

Any help would be most sincerely appreciated

Comment: No; Your speeds are below average.  As for the transfer from a portable SSD that would entirely depend on the specifications of that drive.

Comment: @Ramhound the portable SSD is a 1TB samsung T7, it's when I copy something from T7 to the nvme of my laptop I get speeds that plummet to 20 MB/s, but is fine for files that are around 1GB. So, would you say that this nvme that I have is faulty?

Comment: Are we talking about USB 3.2 Gen 1 or something faster?

Comment: @Ramhound USB 3.2 gen 2

Answer (score 1):

For a QLC-based SSD those speeds are probably somewhat normal. [Your SSD](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/204109/intel-ssd-670p-series-1-0tb-m-2-80mm-pcie-3-0-x4-3d4-qlc/specifications.html) uses QLC (quad-level cell) flash storage, which is cheap but rather slow in general.

The advertised speeds are high because the SSD also has some amount of very fast SLC (single-level) flash memory, which is used to accept all new writes. According to [AnandTech](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16503/the-intel-ssd-670p-review) the 512 GB model has "6–70 GB" of SLC cache, whatever that means<sup>1</sup>.

So when you copy just a 1 GB file, it's written to the SLC cache at full advertised speed. (Later, when the SSD is idle, its firmware automatically moves new data from cache to main QLC storage without anybody noticing.)

But if you suddenly write more data than the cache can hold, then those writes begin going *directly* to the QLC flash, and that's when you see the real write speed that QLC offers.

<sup>1</sup> (It [looks like](https://images.anandtech.com/doci/16318/670p-cache.png) the SSD can dynamically use the same physical flash as either SLC or QLC, so the more space you have used, the less space you have for cache. This means that TRIM usage becomes even more important, as it directly affects the amount of write cache you have.)